# create a tiff image

Tags: java, html, image, tiff

How to create a tiff image using HTML form data in java?
I have few text fields in my HTML page and I would like to generate a tiff file using that data

-PD

Comment: what do you mean by HTML form data?

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide more information in my post. I have few text fields in my HTML page and I would like to generate a tiff file using that information.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jaifaq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Java(TM) Image I/O API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/downloads/download-iio-1_0_01.html) will allow you to read and write TIFF files among other formats.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but the following thread in JGuru forum might help.
http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=501181